# full free library that reads doc .net 2.0

Tags: library, c#, .net, office, microsoft-word

I've searched a lot for a full free library that reads doc files without office being installed

1. I've tried NetOffice and it used interop and needs installed office
2. I've tried Free Spire.Net and it's limited for 100 lines only
3. NPOI .doc reading has deprecated

I'm using for excel xls ,xlsx & docx  NPOI but didn't find a free library that reads .doc file ?!

Answer (score 1):

[Essential DocIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio) is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify.

Essential DocIO doesn't require Office to be installaed and can read .DOC and .DOCX files. .NET 2.0 is also supported.